# Function to calculate portions and instance of a class in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, custom-data-type

in preparation for an exam on haskell our teacher gave us some exercises but was then sick on the day we were supposed to discuss them.
Some of them I solved, some of them I can't figure out:

1) Write a function that calculates the parts of vodka and energy in a longdrink:

```
data VodkaEnergy = Vodka Int | Energy Int | Mix VodkaEnergy VodkaEnergy
```

I didn't manage to do much more than:

```
mixPortion :: VodkaEnergy->(Int,Int)
mixPortion (Vodka x) = (x,0)
mixPortion (Energy y) = (0,y)
mixPortion (Mix x y) = (a,b)
 where a = fst (mixPortion x)
       b = snd (mixPortion y)
```

I realize this is a oversimplified solution that doesn't catch all inputs but I'm at a loss.

1b) VodkaEnergy should be a part of Eq, making 2 longdrinks equal if they have the same ratio of vodka and energy.

This one I can't solve until I have the function but I'm assuming it would go like this:

```
instance Eq VodkaEnergy where
 x == y    = mixPortion x == mixPortion y
```

typeclasses are still difficult for me, so do correct me.

2) Write a function that counts the paths that has an even amount of Leaves + Nodes in

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Ndoe Int Tree Tree
```

Again, at a loss all I got so far is a function that counts all nodes and leaves in the tree, which doesn't help much

3)

```
data Eq a => Set a = S [a]
```

Make set an instance of Eq, where two sets are the same if all elements of set1 are contained in set2 and vice versa.

This one confuses me because the data type in the task doesn't compile with the "Eq a =>" there. But what I tried so far is this:

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Set a) where
 x:set1 == set2      = x `elem` set2 && set1 == set2 && set2 == set1
```

but the "x:set1" part doesn't compile because it expects a different type

I know these are probably newbie questions. I mean, I AM a newbie to haskell. I'm finding it hard to find good ressources for questions on haskell like these, so do link me if I missed the answers floating on the web somewhere. I'm honestly a little desperate, the exam is coming closer and I still don't quite 'get' functional programming.
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: 1a) Looks good, but you always need to add the whole tuples together, not just `fst` or `snd`; 1b) looks good;

Comment: 2) Have you tried extracting a list of all the possible paths?

Comment: 3) I don't know what `x:set1` is supposed to mean, this is not Haskell syntax. You just need the two sets/variables `set1` and `set2` (or `x` and `y` like you used in the longdrink example) and then use some function that checks your desired criterion.

Comment: @snøreven x:set1 is a pattern match on a list. @banzai You have to match on the `S` constructor from Set too. So `S (x:set1)`.

Comment: ad 3: Sorry I went over that too quickly: The data type doesn't compile because standard Haskell doesn't allow typeclass restrictions here (there is the GADTs extensions for doing things like that). You are doing it right with the restriction on the `Eq` instance. In your `(==)` function you can just pattern match the "wrapped" lists like so `(S xs) == (S ys) = ...` and then use the "Set" operations from `Data.List` on them.

Comment: @banzai Also you are missing the pattern match on `S []`.

Comment: @snøreven I don't think using the set operations from `Data.List` was the intention of the assignment.

Comment: One question per post only, please. After all, an answer might focus only on one of those questions. Which of the answers will you accept? Instead of a StackOverflow answer, you _might_ need a Haskell mentor/tutor.

Comment: @Zata: I think that whole thing is more of a topic for the chat than a StackOverflow question anyway.

Comment: Let's move to chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132110/function-to-calculate-portions-and-instance-of-a-class-in-haskell

Comment: @banzai I'm a bit unclear what a path is in 2.. Is this only paths from the root to a leaf or paths from any node to a leaf or paths from any node to any node or leaf?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it would actually be worse to clutter the board with questions rather than posting one. Will remember for the future. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. a) Almost good, but you have to add up the vodka and energy components of both parts of the mix, not just the vodka from the first and the energy from the second. Furthermore it is often nicer to use pattern-matching instead of accessor methods like `fst` and `snd` if possible.

   ```
   mixPortion :: VodkaEnergy -> (Int,Int)
   mixPortion (Vodka x)  = (x,0)
   mixPortion (Energy y) = (0,y)
   mixPortion (Mix x y)  = (v1+v2,e1+e2)
     where (v1,e1) = (mixPortion x)
           (v2,e2) = (mixPortion y)
   ```

   b) is correct.
2. As I said in the comment I don't really know what exactly question wants. Assuming that the task is to find the number of even paths from the root to any leaf, you could approach it like this: You write a function `evenOddBranches :: Tree -> (Int,Int)` that gives the number of even paths and odd paths. This is easier, since an even path of a subtree of a node is an odd path if you add that node to the path. That way you get a simple recursion: The number even paths of a node are the sum of the odd paths of it's two subtrees and the number odd paths is the sum of the even paths of the subtrees.
3. The `Eq` constraint on `Set` used to be correct syntax but isn't anymore since Haskell 2010. The correct way to do this is to just leaf out the `Eq` constraint in the data definition and add it where needed.

   There are also some flaws with your code. First of all you can not pattern-match on it with `x:set1`, because it is not a list, but a `Set`, which means you have the `S` wrapper. So instead you have to pattern-match like this: `S (x:xs)`. Note that `xs` is a list and not a `Set`, so for the recursive call you have to wrap it with `S` again. Furthermore if you match on `S (x:xs)` you should also match on `S []`. So fixing your code on a syntactical level we get the following:

   ```
   data Set a = S [a]
   instance (Eq a) => Eq (Set a) where
     S [] == S []     = True
     S [] == S (_:_)  = False
     S (x:xs) == S ys = x `elem` ys && S xs == S ys && S ys == S xs
   ```

   This will compile but does not work. For example with `S [0] == S [0]` is `False`.

   The easiest way to write a set equality is with two set inclusions. So you should write a function `subsetEq :: Eq a => Set a -> Set a -> Bool` that is `True` iff every element of the first set is also an element of the second set. Then you can implement set equality like this:

   ```
   instance (Eq a) => Eq (Set a) where
     set1 == set2 = set1 `subsetEq` set2 && set2 `subsetEq` set1
   ```

   I think with only an `Eq` constraint this is actually the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. as for task #2, it's supposed to count all even paths starting from the root. But I'm working on something for that now thanks to the advice and i think i got it.